# Python 3.5 - Output from file

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, file-io

My goal is to have two programs. One will ask the user to input a test name and then a test score repeatedly until the user hits enter. This information will be stored in a .txt file. The second program will pull the information from the .txt file and print it into a format like something below with the test scores and a final average:

```
Reading six tests and scores
TEST          SCORE
objects       88
loops         95
selections    86
variables     82
Average Test Score is
```

So far I have this for the first program to generate the txt document:

```
def main():
    myfile = open('test.txt', 'w')
    test = input('Please enter test name or enter to quit ')

    while test != '':
        score = int(input('Enter % score on this test '))
        myfile.write(test + '\n')
        myfile.write(str(score) + '\n')
        test = input('Please enter test name or enter to quit ')

    myfile.close()
    print('File was created successfully')

main()
```

The second program looks like this and is in rough shape:

```
def main():
    f = open('test.txt', 'r'); 
    text = f.read(); 
    f.close()
Main()
```

Any suggestions or examples? I’m really struggling.

Comment: Fix your indentation please...

Comment: use `print(test, file=myfile)` instead of `myfile.write`. You get the `'\n'` for free :)

Answer (score 0):

### First program / write

I recommend using `\t` between name and score instead of `\n`.

like this...

```
name1    100
name2    75
name3    10
...
```

It will help you when you read a file.

`name, score = file.readline().split('\t')`

Additionally, How about check input validation? whether input value in the valid range.

### Second program / read

Using format is a nice way.

```
total, count = 0, 0
fmt = "{name:<16}\t{score:<5}"
header = fmt.format(name="TEST", score="SCORE")
print(header)
while ( ... ):
    total += score
    count += 1
    ... # read file
    row = fmt.format(name=name, score=score)
    print(row)
print("Average Test Score is ", total/count)
```